# How to use regexpression in Javascript with 5alphabets, 4number and 1 alphabet when on change event happens in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this piece of code by using on click event. But in Javascript that validation is not happening could any one suggest me how to go about?

Here is my sample piece of code:
My HTML code inside body tag:

```
<div id="cca" class="leaf">
 <label class="control input text" title="">
    <span class="wrap">cca</span>
     <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
    <span class="warning"></span>
 </label>
</div>
<div id="tan" class="leaf">
 <label class="control input text" title="">
    <span class="wrap">tan</span>
     <input class="" type="text" value="[Null]"/>
    <span class="warning"></span>
 </label>
```

Jquery script is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#tan label.control input', function (event) {
    var txtan=document.querySelector('#tan label.control input ').value;

    if(txtan!=""){
        jQuery("#cca").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',true);
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if(txtan==""){
        jQuery("#cca").find('label.control input').prop('disabled',false);
    } 
    if(txtan.match(/^[A-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-z]{1}$1/i)==null){
        alert("Please enter 5 alphabetic 4 numeric and 1 alphabet only in the field");
        return false;
    }else{
        alert("Correct..."+txtan);
    }


});
```

after changes also its not working

Answer (score 1):

Change the regexp to:

```
/^[a-z]{5}[0-9]{4}[a-z]{1}$/i
```

Mixing case in the range `A-z` doesn't work, because there are punctuation characters between `Z` and `a`. You should use a single case, and the `i` modifier to make it case-insensitive.

The range `[A-z]` contains the following characters, as you can see in the [ASCII Chart](http://www.asciitable.com/):

- A through Z
- `` [ \ ] ^ _ ` ``
- a through z

So when you used your regular expression, it allowed those symbols in the middle in addition to letters.

I also changed it to use `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of the input. Otherwise, it will allow any input as long as there's one word that matches the pattern in it, e.g.

```
foo abcde1234z bar
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/YywW8/1/)

Comment: Barmar, please check edited content how am using. In that if it is true or false also it is showing alert as "Please enter 5 alphabetic 4 numeric and 1 alphabet only in the field". how to control

Comment: Please don't change your original question. If you want to show what you've changed, add it to the end in an `UPDATE` section. Otherwise, my answer doesn't make sense. Anyway, the problem is you still have `A-z` instead of `a-z`.

Comment: You also have an extra `1` after `$`.

Comment: Barmar, i need only 5 alphabets 4 number and 1 alphabet only should i remove that 1 or what to do? if i remove that 1 after $ still it is showing same alert

Comment: The `{1}` before `$` sets 1 alphabet. The `1` after `$` is just plain wrong, you can't have anything after the end of the string. Have you fixed `A-z`?

Comment: Shorter : `/^[a-z]{5}\d{4}[a-z]$/i`. `[A-z]` seems not to cause any problem in my Chrome console.

Comment: @wared I didn't want to confuse things with any changes that weren't totally necessary to fix the problem.

Comment: @Barmar `/[A-z]/.test('[') -> true`, `/[A-z]/.test('A') -> true`, `/[A-z]/.test('-') -> false`... Now I understand your comment but I don't understand this result. Have you got any idea?

Comment: Look at an [ASCII chart](http://www.asciitable.com/), and see the characters that are between `A` and `z`. They include 6 symbols between `Z` and `a`.

Comment: That was obvious! Silly me ^^' Thanks a lot @Barmar, this is really nice to take time to answer :)